# Trying to crawl a website with some redirections

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler, guzzle, domcrawler

I want to scrape informations from a website however I can't have the access to this website until I don't check the checkbox.

So in order to access to my data I have to :

- connect to the website URL
- find the form and check a checkbox
- validate the form and go an a new link
- click on a new button
- access to my data.

I don't know if it is possible / easy to do because I never scraped anything
(just to prevent this is totally legal and I am not trying to access to confidential data)

Here is my PHP Script. I'm using Symfony DomCrawler and GuzzleHttp.

```
// Imports and display errors etc...
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get("website.com");
$htmlString = $response->getBody();

$crawler = new Crawler($htmlString,'website.com');
//I'm writting the website address twice bc when I only use guzzle the program display an error of relative URL or something like that.


// Select the input checkbox
$checkbox = $crawler->filter('#condition')->first();
//I tried here to do this : $checkbox->attr('checked','checked'); as Chat GPT suggest me but it didn't work
var_dump($checkbox->attr('checked')); // Here the value is NULL 
// So I think I make a mistake here bc the value of the attr of the checkbox is NULL


$form = $crawler->filter('form')->last()->form(); // Select the form 

$actionUri = $form->getUri(); 
echo $actionUri;// here is the next url 
$client->post($actionUri, [
    'form_params' => $form->getValues(),
    'allow_redirects' => [
        'max' => 10, // maximum number of redirects to follow
        'strict' => true, // whether to apply strict RFC 2616 protocol redirect rules
        'referer' => true, // whether to add a Referer header
        'protocols' => ['http', 'https'], // allowed redirect protocols
        'track_redirects' => true // whether to return an array of all redirect responses
    ]
]);
// After this script I don't know how I am supposed to continue through the other page
```

In fact I tried to connect as an usual URL like so

```
//the script above + : 
$url = 'SecondStep.com';
$nextCrawler = new Crawler('',$url); 
// but here this url seems to redirect me to the first URL
```

So I don't know what I'm supposed to do.

Sorry for my terrible english.

Conclusion :
I wan't to check a checkbox input and to go an the next URL after click on the submit button

Comment: _scrap = 
: to abandon or get rid of as no longer of enough worth or effectiveness to retain_

Comment: oh yes sorry. I meant scraping

Comment: Trying to pass a captcha with a robot, and then copy content, is indeed legal. What you do with the content after that might not be legal. You are asking us to help you with that.

Comment: I would not suggest asking for help to bypass captcha. Who ever runs the website you are trying to scrape has added the captcha to prevent robots to access the content. Although having a basic understanding of how captcha functions may assist in bypassing it, modern captcha systems typically use a range of metrics to determine whether a user is human or not. Even if it appears to be just a checkbox, there are usually many factors involved.

Comment: it is not a real captcha and the data is completly open to everyone. 
When I say captcha it is just a checkbox for terms of use.

Comment: SecondStep.com starts with a [Google reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/) and that is very real. Google may only present a checkbox to you, or even nothing, but it only does that when it is familiar with your internet connection, computer and browser. Websites use captchas to protect their content from robots, like the one you're planning to make. In other words: You want to go directly against the wishes of the people behind the website. Should you?

Comment: I'm not sure it is a captcha. It is just a form to agree to terms of use. My boss asked me to do it and i'm currently stuck. The previous trainees did this program however they loss the file. I'm supposed to recreate it but I'm stuck. that is why i' m asking for your help :/ Also my boss don't really know about coding, he is a lawyer. As for me it seems illegal however he's sure it is not. (he's the lawyer + the boss ...)